# Protractor "Bad inspector message"

Tags: angularjs, protractor

What does this mean? Someone who knows? "Bad inspector.." see below:

```
10:40:24.078 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chrome, version=ANY}]]
10:40:24.098 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 11000])
10:40:24.102 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 11000]
10:40:24.258 INFO - Executing: [get: data:text/html,<html></html>])
[1.102][SEVERE]: Bad inspector message: {"method":"Page.loadEventFired","params":{"timestamp":4554,055703}}
[1.102][SEVERE]: Bad inspector message: {"method":"Page.domContentEventFired","params":{"timestamp":4554,056032}}
10:40:54.258 INFO - Executing: [execute async script: try { return (function (rootSelector, ng12Hybrid, callback) {
  var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);
```

I am the only one in my company who can't run the tests, and I don't know what is causing it.

Comment: can you please post the content of your project's config.js and spec.js files?

Comment: Agree. Additional information is also required. Having just the webdriver logs is not enough. Other things that should be included are the chromedriver version and chrome version.

Comment: Probably this will help you:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3672

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1552#c38